# Where is the production.log in Ubuntu 14.04 - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04, aws-opsworks

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 in OpsWorks and I have in my production.rb file this configuration:

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

The problem is that I can not find the production.log in my server, I read that probably is because the user that runs the application doesn't have the correct permission to write the file. What is the correct path for production.log? If the problem is users permissions where I can change it in Opsworks?

Comment: Which AP Server do you use, unicorn, passenger, WeBrick and anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `stderr_path` and `stdout_path` to your `unicorn.rb`
If you don't write their methods, unicorn's default output path is `/dev/null` when daemonized.

```
# #{Rails.root}/config/unicorn.rb
stderr_path "#{Rails.root}/log/unicorn_error_#{Rails.env}.log"
stdout_path "#{Rails.root}/log/unicorn_#{Rails.env}.log"
```

More Detail is [Unicorn Congigular](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html#method-i-stderr_path)